# nuget package recovery program is getting 404:not found

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

my project is using package.config file.

but when i load api packages, nuget gets me error with package recovery.

so I thought this was a problem with the online source list.

there wasn't any remote source list on nuget, so I added 'https://nuget.org'.

but still, I get bunch of 404 not found msg with nuget when i try to recover my

api package.

query is https://nuget.org: 'https://www.nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='packagename'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'

any recomms are welcomed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> nuget package recovery program is getting 404:not found

Please make sure you have available package source nuget.org with the source value **`https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`** instead of `https://nuget.org`:

Check it from Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager->Package Sources:

[image]

Then click OK button to save it.

If you still can not restore your package, please check if you can open the source `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` in the browser directly.

Hope this helps.